# Can feature requests not be questions?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, feature-request-process

Even as a someone who is something of a UI/UXtist myself, I found it pretty awkward to navigate to the right place to submit feedback. I don't want a "Ask Question" button, I want a "Submit feedback that will probably never be read by anybody important" button.

Typing this I noticed a similar feedback post from 2014, so I guess it's one of those old familiar "eh" suggestions that might get addressed after everything else. Which is fair.

A simple change to lessen confusion a bit would be to conditionally alter the button text from "Ask Question" to "Submit Request" when the requests tab is selected. The next low-effort change could be to add a few buttons here and there on all SE sites that link to meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=requests.

Comment: Maybe something like "Create Post" on meta sites?  It is, admittedly, odd that a lot of meta questions aren't actually questions...on the other hand, the "question"/"answer" pairing format is pretty baked into the software.

Comment: @RyanM I think what they're asking about is that feature requests shouldn't be questions on a Q&A site, but rather submitted like a feedback form similar to how it works on many other Internet sites.

Comment: Oh, that sounds worse.  No one ever does anything about those, as the post notes.

Comment: Related question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320341/377214 (Tim Post's answer is relevant here; do note they worked for Stack Exchange at the time, but left the company before proposing experiments.)

Comment: In reference to the point made about feature requests vs. Q&A, I feel that having to use meta.stackexchange.com to submit feedback for ex. something related to Stack Overflow's search functionality also seems like an unintuitive and roundabout way of doing things from the perspective of a new visitor, but that's another kettle of fish.

Comment: I should note that when Stack Exchange was originally established in 2008, it used a UserVoice feedback forum for meta. The decision to establish a meta site was made one year later, in 2009.

Comment: You can also submit Stack Overflow-specific feedback on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: More recently, and categorically similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376996/282094

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky because what you ask here is changing wording based on tags.

This would be confusing to see wording changed all over the place when viewing different questions.

And even worse, often people choose wrong tags to begin with, most common using [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [support](/questions/tagged/support) for feature requests, so they won't even "enjoy" such a change in wording.

Bottom line, I'm afraid there's very little actual use in what you suggest.